# Solve_vbp with boundary conditions and arrays

Tags: python, solver, differential-equations

I try to solve DE with boundary conditions, but every time get this error. I edited my code with notes, that i getted, but a still have an error.
I understand that it's an error because I cant give functions for `solve_bvp` as a vector `f1, f2 = y`, but I dont know another way.

In variables:

u1,u2 = const

x1, x2, x22 = array

f1, f2 = functions

I have 20 point in DE and 20 values in arrays. I dont understand :c

Code:

```
t_eval = np.array([0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70, 77, 84, 91, 98, 105, 112, 119, 126, 133, 140]) 
u2=0.2
u1=1.2
x1=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
x2=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
x22=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

def f1f2_model(t, y):
a1 = np.interp(t_eval, x1, f1[1])
a2 = np.interp(t_eval, x2, f2[1])
b1 = np.interp(t_eval, x1, f1[1])
b2 = np.interp(t_eval, x1, f2[1])
df1_dt = u1 * a1 - u1 * a2
df2_dt = u1 * b1 -u1 *b2-u2*f2 + 2*(x2-x22)
return np.vstack((u1 * a1 - u1 * a2), (u1 * b1 -u1 *b2-u2*f2[1] + 2*(x2-x22)))

def bc(f1_T, f2_T):
    return np.array([f1_T[0], f2_T[0]])

T=140
n=20
x = np.linspace(0, T, n)
y = np.array([x, np.full_like(x, 673), np.linspace(800, 200, n)])

sol = spi.solve_bvp(f1f2_model, bc, x, y)
  
print(sol.y)
```

error still about "too many values"

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d9d4806ecb60> in <module>
      7 #Решаем через solve_bvp
      8 #sol = spi.solve_bvp(f1f2_model, bc, x, y)
----> 9 sol = spi.solve_bvp(f1f2_model(t, y), bc, t, y)
     10 
     11 t = np.linspace(0, T, 20)

<ipython-input-2-019ad077bd9c> in f1f2_model(t, y)
     10 def f1f2_model(t, y):
     11 
---> 12     f1, f2 = y
     13     a1 = np.interp(t_eval, x1, f1[1])
     14     a2 = np.interp(t_eval, x2, f2[1])

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: So if the situation is not completely strange, `x1` etc. is a function of `t`. How do you think the correct function value is selected? Study `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`, or use `numpy.interp` directly inside the ODE function. Also read again the documentation of `solve_bvp` and how function parameters are used for variable constants of the ODE system.

Comment: Can I give parametrs of function with `np.interp` as 
`df1_dt = u1 * np.interp(t_eval, x1, f1) - u1 * np.interp(t_eval, x2, f2)`?

Comment: Not exactly like that, it should be `np.interp(t,t_arr, x1_arr)` for the actual value of `x1` at time `t`. Similarly for the others. You do not need to pass unchanging constants as function parameters, they are as well available as global variables. If you compute multiple solutions for different parameters, passing these changing parameters as function arguments makes more sense. Another reason could be a structuring of the code into packages, actually or as guiding principle. But then it would also make sense to build a class around the function with the parameters passed on construction.

Comment: I.e. it should be  `for t in range (T) np.interp(x1, f1) `?

Comment: No, `t_arr, x1_arr` is the function value table, `t` the time you want a value for. As a numpy function, it also provides the possibility for a multi-point evaluation, where `t` is a list of points.

Comment: OK, i take x1, x2,x22 as a const for Example. And i still have an erros `too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. 
I understand that my problem is a vestor `f1, f2 = y`in my `def` and I dont understand at all how to fix it. How i can give 2 functoins in `solve_bvp`?

Comment: About `np.interp`. How i can give 2 values (as x,y) for my x1 if i have only x? (sry, x and t) but dont have a `t_arr` as an y

Comment: many thx for ur help!